# Unique Constrant and Data Normalization in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have the following tables *(I've removed constraints and unrelated columns for brevity)*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INT,
    user_name VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id INT
);
CREATE TABLE book_author (
    book_author_id INT,
    book_id INT,
    author_name VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE book_author_user_match (
    book_author_id INT,
    user_id INT
)
```

The `book_author_user_match` table stores potentials matches of a user to their book, which is determined by searching the authors and looking for matching names. A user should only be matched to a book once, so if multiple authors matched a specific user, I only want to store one entry and only send one notification to that user for the given book.

Here's the part I'm stuck on. It's easy enough to add a `book_id` column and unique constraint on `(book_id, user_id)`. However, I don't want to add a `book_id` column on the table, because the `book_author` table can be joined on the `book_author_id` column to find the `book_id`. In other words, having both a `book_author_id` and `book_id` column on the table is de-normalizing the data.

The only options I see are:

1. add the `book_id` column and just live with de-normalized data
2. don't have a unique constraint, and instead ensure one `user_id` per book at the code level

Neither of these options feels "right" to me. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can enforce one user match per book without de-normalizing the data, or is this a situation where it's okay to have denormalized data?

*I realize parts of this question are opinionated, but I'm mainly looking for alternatives that I haven't thought of*

Comment: I don't see any normalization problems with your current approach.

Comment: Are you sure that your "authors" write *only one book*? (1:N relation between `book` and `author`). Additionally if you want to model a relation between `user` and `book` *do not* create a relation between `user` and `author`....

Comment: The authors are coming from an API and all I get is a list of names. So I don't have a table of authors, which is why the structure is the way it is. I see your point that if I want unique matches I should create the relationship between `user` and `book`, but I do want to store that I matched author X to user Y so I can look at which author name was matched to a specific user. However, now that I think about it maybe I don't need that info.

Comment: You may add the `search author` as an attribute of the relation `user` to `book`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber So you are saying to add something like `author_name` to `book_author_user_match`? That's not a bad idea and I like that more than having a `book_id` and `book_author_id` that are both FKs. It still feels a bit like de-normalized data, but since it's not a FK I don't mind so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to store authors in a separate table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INT,
    user_name VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id INT
);
CREATE TABLE author (
    author_id INT,
    author_name VARCHAR
);    
CREATE TABLE book_author (
    book_author_id INT,
    book_id INT,
    author_id INT
);
CREATE TABLE book_author_user_match (
    book_author_id INT,
    user_id INT
)
```

And set user_id and book_author_id either as primary or just as unique key

Comment: The books and authors are coming from an API, so I don't have any author IDs and I'm not managing them myself. I'm just getting a list of author names along with the books, which is why I'm storing them in a `book` and `book_author` table. I wish there was some kind of unique ID for each author, but it's a 3rd party API and I have no control over it. The whole point to this is to query these authors and try to match them to specific users that do have IDs

Comment: Also, you're answer does not answer my question of how to enforce a unique constraint of one user match per book. If I set `user_id` and `book_author_id` as a primary or unique key, there could be multiple authors per book matched to the same user.

Answer (score 0):

You have users who can be authors. Maybe one user even represents two or more authors (i.e. writes under various pseudonyms). A 1:n relation (a user ID in the author table).

Then there are books. A book can be written by several authors and an author can write several books. An m:n relation (which requires a bridge table).

This is the data model that I see:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id      INT      NOT NULL,
    user_name    VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE author (
    author_id    INT      NOT NULL,
    author_name  VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    user_id      INT      NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (author_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id      INT      NOT NULL,
    title        VARCHAR  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE book_author (
    book_id      INT      NOT NULL,
    author_id    INT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, author_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(author_id)
);
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear in my original question. The books and authors are coming from a 3rd party API and all I get is a list of author names. I do not manage the author list and there is no unique ID, which is why I have the structure I do. The point to this is to grab these books and authors from the API, and try to match the books to one of my users based on the author names.

Comment: So how does that render my answer wrong? You get authors and you want to assign them a user if possible. So the author table has a user_id which you fill if you see a user matching.

Comment: If a book can only be written by one author you can remove the `book_author` table of course and add an `author_id` to the `book` table instead. (Thus making the relation 1:n instead of m:n.)

Comment: Hmm, I see where you are going, but the problem is I could have many duplicate entries in the `author` table. I don't have any kind of unique ID for the authors I am getting, so let's say out of 100 books, 10 of them have a John Smith. I don't know if those 10 are the same john smith or different. Now let's say I have a user named John Smith, who happens to be the author on one of those books but not the other. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: In other words, I can't say I'm gong to always match an author named John Smith to a user named John Smith. If I had a unique ID for each author, then yes your solution would be perfect and is what I would have done in the first place.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. You get authors, you insert authors. You can create an ID for an author you insert. Is the problem that two books can be written by some John Smith, but you cannot know whether this is the same John Smith?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem.

Comment: It's also complicated by the fact the the author names are very inconsistent and sometimes all I get are a last name and first initial, so there's a lot of potential for duplicates.

Comment: The other point is this doesn't address my actual question, which is how to enforce a unique constraint so a user cannot be matched to a book more than once. Let's say I have a user named John Smith and get the authors J Smith and John Smith. Both of these would match, and I would have the same user matched twice to one book.

Comment: Then this is mainly about consolidating authors. If you notice there is a book both written by 'J. Smith' and ' John Smith', then both authors are supposed to be the same person. Delete 'J. Smith' and stay with 'John Smith' only. If there are two 'John Smith' and you notice these are two different authors then somehow make this visble in the name e.g. 'J. Smith, born 1962', and 'J. Smith, born 1902'. My datamodel is still appropriate. However, I will write another answer where there is no consolidation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting books from another system. The list may be as follows:

- The Good Book, author John Smith
- The Great Book, authors John Smith, Jane Smith
- The Better Book, author J. Smith

You don't know whether the two John Smiths are the same person, whether J. Smith is some John Smith, some Jane Smith or still someone else. In the worst case there may even be an author who uses both pseudonyms John Smith and Jane Smith.

In a comment to my other answer you say you don't want the same person to be mentioned as a book's author twice. In this scenario it is impossible for Mr. X to use both pseudonyms John Smith and Jane Smith and write The Great Book alone (or you'd need another author pseudonym called 'Jane and John Smith' for this author :-)

This can be done with a book authors table with an optional user ID and a unique constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id      INT      NOT NULL,
    user_name    VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id      INT      NOT NULL,
    title        VARCHAR  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE book_author (
    book_id      INT      NOT NULL,
    author_name  VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    user_id      INT      NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, author_name),
    UNIQUE KEY (book_id, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
```

Comment: This is close but it assumes that an author can only match one user. Remember, this is storing potential matches, so if I get an author name J Smith, and I have users named John Smith and Jane Smith, I would need to store a _potential_ match to both of those users. That's why I had the matches table as a one to many in the first place.

Comment: I really appreciate all the time you put into going through this with me, but I'm just gonna stick with my original model and instead of having an unique constraint at the database, do the check at the code level.